# Reply to messages on chat starwalls

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

I'm a member of Code Review; we have a very (star-happy) chat room called [The 2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor). It's not uncommon to want to make a reply to a message on the starwall and start a conversation based off of that message.

There's no option to reply to something on the starwall by using the drop-down menu for each message; you only have the ability to create a permalink, flag, star/unstar or view history of the comment, so in order to reply to a comment currently you have to hover over the timestamp (which has a link to the original comment) and copy the original ID into chat by hand.

Could an item be added to the dropdown menu that allows you to quickly reply to that specific comment? All I would expect it to do is just populate the chat box with `:messageId` (where messageId is the Id of the message you're replying to).

Comment: Actually you can middle-click the permalink to have it open in new tab, and you can Reply there, from the transcript. Not ideal, but better than manually writing the message ID as you're doing now

Comment: I appreciate this is a duplicate, but the "original" question is awfully old (2011 with no official response yet - I hadn't found it in search, either, before posting this). What can I do to draw more attention to the original question to give it some more attention? @ShadowWizard

Comment: Not much we can do, I started a bounty, but even this only very rarely draw any official response.